# I am not understanding this step

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, interpolation

I am starting the chapter on differential equations and have this example to work through but I do not understand a few things

Solve $dy=\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2x(y-1)}{x^2+1}$

**solution:**

note that $y(x)=1 $ is a solution (where does this come from?)

now assume that $y(x)\neq1$ and separate the variables

$\frac{dy}{y-1}= \frac{2x}{x^2+1}$ (this I understand)

$\int\frac{dy}{y-1}dy=\int \frac{2x}{x^2+1}dx$

$ln|y-1| = ln(x^2+1)+c$

why on LHS is there no $+C$ and why is the RHS $ln(x^2+1)$ and not $ln|x^2+1|$

Comment: 1) $\ln|y-1|+C_1 = \ln(x^2+1)+C_2.$ Denote  $C=C_2-C_1.$    
2) $x^2+1>0$

Comment: Anytime you divide by an expression with a variable, consider if that expression is zero.  Case in point  $y-1 = 0$.  This becomes important because it is possible to lose solutions.  <br>  Likewise, be aware, multiplying by a variable expression can introduce extraneous solutions. <br> For example, start with $x+5=10$ and multiply both sides by x.  $x^2+5x= 10x$ now has an extra solution, x=0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the solution $y(x)=1$ just try setting both sides to $0$.

$x^2+1$ is strictly positive, so $\ln(x^2+1)=\ln|x^2+1|$.

Finally you can write the LHS as $\ln|y-1|+c_1$, and the RHS as $\ln(x^2+1)+c_2$. Then $c=c_2-c_1$. So only one side needs the constant.

Comment: Thank you for a very clear explanation